# How to get blur effect without using BackdropFilter in Flutter?

Tags: image, canvas, dart, flutter, blur

I'm using an image as my background in my project in hand in flutter and to get a nice look, i have a applied a nice blur effect and white overlay with blendmode set to overlay to get a brightness effect. It works fine in my phone but I have tried phones with lower hardware and it lags horribly. I had a similar problem in my web project and it was simply solved by blurring the image once in canvas and getting it as an base64 dataUrl, in flutter though couldn't achieve this.
Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: does it lag even in release mode?

Comment: Yup, unfortunately it does.